# Windows Phone 8 IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone, filestream, isolatedstorage

I'm making a WP8.1 Silverlight app, it's basically done, but I have one big problem.

```
public void CheckAndCopyDBToIsoStore(params bool[] list)
{
    // Obtain a reference to the application's isolated storage
    IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    //Only copy db file over if it does not already exist
    if (!iso.FileExists("TankolasKonyveloDB.sdf") || (list.Length == 1 && list[0] == true))
    {
        using (Stream input = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("TankolasKonyveloDB.sdf",
       UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream output = iso.CreateFile("TankolasKonyveloDB.sdf"))
            {
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                // Copy the file from the install folder to isolated storage.
                while ((bytesRead = input.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                output.Close();
                output.Dispose();
                iso.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have this method in App.xaml.cs, it is called once in the constructor on application start without parameters and it copies the empty database to the isostore if it's not already there. It's working well. The next thing I'd like to  do is, that if I click a button I call this method again with a `bool` argument with a value of `true`. When I do this, I want to copy the empty database again over the existing in runtime.

At the line

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream output = iso.CreateFile("TankolasKonyveloDB.sdf")
```

I get an exception:

> Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

I googled it and the answers were I must close and dispose the connection and everything, but the problem is still there. Instead of `iso.CreateFile` I tried `OpenFile` with `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, `Create` and `CreateNew`... None of them worked.

So the thing is, I want to copy the `.sdf` file to the isostore if it doesn't already exist and I don't want to copy it again on every startup, unless I express that by clicking that button.

If somebody has a solution to this or an idea, please help me!